# Data inside the width of container, While having other CSS styling intact

Tags: css

I need to have the data inside the width of my container. While having other css styling intact.
Have trouble achieving the same. Would appreciate your help.

Working fiddle of the same: http://jsfiddle.net/nco694Le/

Below `Big word here` goes outside the width of container

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class ="collapse">data1 <span class ="DataRightAlign"> small </span ></p>
  <p class ="collapse">data2 <span  class ="DataRightAlign"> small</span></p>
  <p class ="collapse">data3 <span  class ="DataRightAlign"> big word here</span></p> 
</div >
```

Css:

```
.container{
  width: 110px;
  border-style: ridge;  
}

.collapse {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
}

.collapse:after {
  content: '' !important;
  flex: auto !important;
  min-width: 24px !important;
  margin: 0 6px !important;
  height: 2px !important;
  color: lightgrey !important;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,currentColor 2px,transparent 1px) !important;
  background-size: 4px 2px !important; 
}

.DataRightAlign {
  flex: none;
}

.DataRightAlign:last-child {
  order: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with to fit the data inside of the container. It was just a matter of increasing the `width` property of the `container`. I also added some padding.

```css
.container{
  width: 110px;
  border-style: ridge;
}

.collapse {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
}

.collapse:after {
  content: '' !important;
  flex: auto !important;
  min-width: 24px !important;
  margin: 0 6px !important;
  height: 2px !important;
  color: lightgrey !important;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,currentColor 2px,transparent 1px) !important;
  background-size: 4px 2px !important; 
}

.DataRightAlign {
  flex: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.DataRightAlign:last-child {
  order: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class ="collapse">data1 <span class ="DataRightAlign"> small </span ></p>
  <p class ="collapse">data2 <span  class ="DataRightAlign"> small</span></p>
  <p class ="collapse">data3 <span  class ="DataRightAlign"> big word</span></p> 
</div>
```

EDIT: I have added `word-wrap` and `white-space` properties to `DataRightAlign` as well as an explicit `width` property. This should work.

Comment: Sorry, I wont be able to increase the width of container as per requirement.

Comment: So then the only option is to make the contents smaller.

Comment: Do we have any options to break the big word at certain place, so that it can go to next line and fit in the container?

Comment: To break the word, you'd need to set a fixed width to the `span`. There are a couple of tricks to try.

Comment: @Sarahrb I have updated the solution, check if it works.

Comment: I would appreciate if there is a possibility for the data(small or big word) to start in the same line as data1, data2, data3. Instead of starting in the previous line. Would look better if it starts on same line.

Comment: Im afraid that with the current structure of your HTML it is very difficult to come up with a good, flexible solution that would work in multiple scenarios with different data. I'd suggest changing the paragraph to a div / span and then the data (data1, data2, data3) in a p tag, the dots can be after to the p tag and finally the DataRightAlign spans next to the p tag. It would be much easier to work with.